# Visual Studio 2010 giving odd errors compiling C++/CLI project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I'm getting a series of odd errors when I try to compile a VS2010 Windows Form Application. The errors that I'm getting are:

error C2871: 'project_6' : a namespace with this name does not exist

error C2653: 'Application' : is not a class or namespace name

error C3861: 'EnableVisualStyles': identifier not found

error C2653: 'Application' : is not a class or namespace name

error C3861: 'SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault': identifier not found

error C2653: 'Application' : is not a class or namespace name

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Form1'

error C3861: 'Run': identifier not found

error C1854: cannot overwrite information formed during creation of the precompiled header in object file: 'c:\users\dan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_6\debug\stdafx.obj'

All of the compiler errors give the file as my main.cpp file save the last one, which gives stdafx.cpp. Below is my main.cpp file (it's the one VS2010 automatically generates):

```
// project_6.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace project_6;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

Anyways, I'm at my wit's end trying to figure out what's wrong with it, and was hoping somebody here could lend some insight.

Comment: I know it's a terrible choice, but I'm in college and a course in C++/CLI is required for my major. If I had my way I'd be taking the Java version of this course.

Edit: But no, the file hasn't been modified.

Comment: Having just created a project like this here, which compiled fine, I realise that the .cpp file is correct, but I suspect your Form1.h file is messed-up - have you done anything using the form editor?

Comment: I found my error. Thanks!

Comment: FFS - if you've found the error say what it is!  Otherwise nobody is helped except yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add at least references to System.Windows.Forms and System.Windows.Drawing.

Comment: It is your problem because nobody here knows where for example namespace project_6 is declared. Maybe you need to substitute directive using project_6 for namespace project_6